# android.support.v4.util.Pair vs android.util.Pair

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I read about `support.v4` lib that allows android backward compatibility.

So IIUC, when there is an ambiguity -  it's always best practice to  import the lib from `android.support.v4 ...`

right?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say "always". For lightweight tactical stuff like `Pair`, OK. For strategic things like `android.app.Fragment` versus `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you need to think it through.

Comment: can you elaborate? not sure I get you. support is subset of the new API. no? can you explain when I won't use the support library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's wise but not always needed.

I this case `Pair` is API 5 and quite usefull class so it was added to `v4`library.

Another example are `Fragments`.  If you want to use `ViewPager` with `Fragments` most probably you need `Fragments` from `v4` as `ViewPager` is from `v4` as well...

Comment: not sure I get you. support is subset of the new API. no? can you explain when I won't use the support library?

Comment: for instance, when you don't need it, ie. targeting high API levels, not using ViewPager, etc. there is no straight rule here. please note that support library adds methods to your .apk too

Comment: whats the advantage of not using it? lighter apk?

Comment: if you don't need, ie not targeting old devices -- don't use. by using i add something extra to your apk. you can use proguard to strip extra classes too. and, as we are talking about apk size, is it still a problem nowadays?

Comment: I understand you thumb rule. But I want to understand the logic behind this. Especially when apk size is not a big matter nowadays. Then why not alway use the support lib?

Comment: @pelotasplus is correct. APK size always matters. Use `android.util.Pair` if you can.