# Should we use android.util.Pair or androidx.core.util.Pair?

Tags: android

I just migrated to AndroidX, and noticed there's a new class called `androidx.core.util.Pair`.

I was wondering, going forward, should I use [`android.util.Pair`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair) or [`androidx.core.util.Pair`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Pair)?

Comment: Definitely, we should migrate to Androidx cause the support library artifacts are being deprecated and all future development is going into AndroidX, so there's no avoiding this migration

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is better to use `androidx.core.util.Pair`, from the docs:

> [(September 21, 2018)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#september-21,-2018)
>
> This is the stable release of Support Library 28.0.0 and is suitable for use in production. This will be the last feature release under the `android.support` packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: But, `android.util.Pair` isn't belongs to `android.support` package.

Comment: if you check this page https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate, you can see that `androidx.core.util.Pair` actually replaces `android.support.v4.util.Pair`. Also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214067/android-support-v4-util-pair-vs-android-util-pair you can check the difference between `android.support.v4.util.Pair` and `android.util.Pair`

Comment: Why Google doesn't deprecate these duplicated classes in Android?